# How can I retain the data type in result.success() method in onMethodCall in Flutter Java?

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am trying to return a `List<List<String>>` back to my Flutter code from my `MainActivity.java`.

I created a

```
new MethodChannel(Objects.requireNonNull(getFlutterEngine()).getDartExecutor(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            
    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("getOTD")) {
            result.success(listOfList);
        }  
    }                
}
```

to return the listOfList variable. However, whenever it always coverts the `List<List<String>>` to `<Object>` while returning the "success" value. How can I make the method return the value without changing the data type? If that is not possible, how can I convert the Object back to `List<List<String>>` in the dart part?

Here is my dart side of the code snippet:

```
  void getOTD() async {
    try {
      otdList = await platform.invokeMethod("getOTD");
      otdList = otdList.cast<List<List<String>>>();
      print(otdList);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I tried casting the variable, but it did not work. I want to perform many operations on that variable later, so I need the `List<List<>String>` format. I have declared otdList in my dart code as follows since I was receiving an Object:

```
List<Object?> otdList = [];
```

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html

Comment: @pskink I tried methods mentioned in the `StandardMessageCodec` class, however, not only the methods are not recognized by flutter (like `readValueOfType` ), but I am also not sure how these are helpful in my case. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: my fault - forget my comment - at first i thought that only primitive types are allowed in lists

Comment: @pskink Did you get how to do it?

Comment: tried `final otdList = await platform.invokeMethod("getOTD") as List<List<String>>;` ?

Comment: @pskink I got `'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<String>>' in type cast` error. However if I set `final otdList = await platform.invokeMethod("getOTD") as List<dynamic>`, and print it, it prints exactly how a list of list of String would get printed. The only problem now lies is converting the `List<dynamic>` to `List<List<String>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for the problem. With help of @pskink it turns out all one needs is a nested for loop.
For example,

```
final dynamicList = await platform.invokeMethod("methodName") as List<dynamic>;
List<List<String>> listOfListString = [];

for (int i = 0; i < dynamicList.length; i++) {
    List<String> subString = [];
    for (int j = 0; j < dynamicList[i].length; j++) {
      subString.add((dynamicList[i][j]).toString());
    }
    listOfListString.add(subString);
  }
```

Then, use the listOfListString anywhere you want. It will be in a List<List> format.